# is reading web.config from a class insecure?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i wanted a way of getting settings without having to look them up every time so i made this simple class. ex:

```
public class CustomConfigSettings
{
    public CustomConfigSettings()
    {
        // Default constructor.
    }

    public string MySetting
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"]; }
    }
}
```

it works fine, but it feels like it might be insecure (for some reason i can't put my finger on). would appreciate feedback on security issues, if any, and any possible alternatives. (webforms; .net 3.5).

Comment: You are not gaining anything with your code: Web.Config is cached.  http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/01/15/web-config-is-cached.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link. but this isn't to increase performance or anything like that, it's simply to avoid having to look up AppSetting names every time they're needed. it's so intellisense will provide all the names. (still on the fence about following through; it's just for convenience.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not insecure by itself. Security depends on who will access your class and if this class permits changes to configurations, then if somebody access your code, he can change settings.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason it would be considered more or less secure to read AppSettings from a class than to read them directly from your code. You're using the proper calls and syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your code.

Anyway you can make the function static, it will look better and do not require creating new instance.